# GATE CS 2009, question 11, does the grammar produce odd-length palindromes?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

This is question 11 from GATE CS 2009.

Find the language generated by the following grammar over the input alphabet  = $\{a,b\}$.

$S \to aSa \mid bSb \mid a \mid b $

The language generated by the above grammar over the alphabet {a,b} is the set of
(A) All palindromes
(B) All odd length palindromes.
(C) Strings that begin and end with the same symbol
(D) All even length palindromes
the ans is b.
i want to know the language for the grammar

Comment: What have you tried? What was your approach? Don't dump your homework here without having thought about it by yourself.

Comment: How can the answer be (C)? The string $abaa$ starts and ends with the same character but can't be generated by the given grammar.

Comment: My approach is very simple.                                                                     The possible palindrome generated by above grammar can be of odd length only as there is no rule for S -> \epsilon
For example generated palindromes are aba, aaa, bab, ababa, aaaaa, ..

Answer (score 2):

> $$S \to aSa \mid bSb \mid a \mid b$$

**Hints:**

(A) All palindromes

- Can you generate the string $abba$ from the languege?

(B) All odd length palindromes.

(C) Strings that begin and end with the same symbol

- Can you generate the string $ababaa$ from the languege?

(D) All even length palindromes.

- Same hint as in (A)

Just add one more production to this grammar i.e S->^(Epsilon) and this grammar works

Comment: aSa -> abSba [replacing S-> bSb] -> ababa[replacing S->a](string start with symbol a and end with a => same symbol)

Answer (score 0):

- Two cases:

  1. Both B and C are appropriate, but since B is a more specific answer, B is correct.
  2. In case of S->a or S->b, there is only a begin symbol and no end symbol.
     Correct me if I am wrong.